# uniVocity parser to handle duplicate header names

Tags: java, csv, univocity

How can I read a csv file which has duplicate column names by using BeanParser.

Below is the example header

> **Col desc, Col amount, Col desc, Col amount**
>
> > test, 12.44, test2, 43.44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the header names manually:

```
public class MyClass {

    @Parsed(field = "amount1")
    private BigDecimal amount1;

    @Parsed(field = "amount2")
    private BigDecimal amount2;

    @Parsed(field = "description1")
    private String description1;

    @Parsed(field = "description2")
    private BigDecimal description2;
}
```

Then:

```
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true); //to read your input headers with duplicates.
parserSettings.setHeaders("description1", "amount1, "description2", "amount2"); //to override the headers in the input with the names you want to work with
```

Then parse:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new CsvRoutines(parserSettings).parseAll(MyClass.class, <input>);
```

You can also use the field index instead of the field names in the annotations, so you don't need to worry about header names.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: No problem, if it helped to solve your problem please upvote / mark the answer as accepted. Best regards

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Here I am adding little bit complexity to the question. The above mentioned columns are not just 4. They are 32, 16 descriptions 16 amounts along with the some other 100 columns. I am thinking to prepare the bean by using BeanParser for 100 columns and populate the other properties manually by getting them from context. is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Not sure what you need to do with the data but it might be easier to not even use a bean, but parse by record. Use 
`parser.parseNextRecord()` or `parser.parselAllRecords()` then get the values like this: `Map<String, String> data = record.toFieldMap()`

Comment: The problem with the above approach is, if the column names are same they are overriding the values because it is a map.

Comment: use `record.toIndexMap`

Comment: or set the header list manually with `parserSettings.setHeaders(""description1", "amount1, "description2", "amount2"...)`

Comment: Thanks Jeronimo Backes. When I set headers manually parser is reading only one row from the file. Same code with out setHeaders(""...) was able to read all the rows. What could be the reason? can you please guide me.